# Android | Creating Folder in External Storage Root Directory on Android 11+

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

As is well known, Google turned the authorization concept upside down from Android 11 and completely changed it.

I looked in the Android documentation jungle, but didn't find an answer to the question of whether it's still possible to create a folder in the root directory of External Storage (named /storage/emulated/0/). **If yes, how?**

My app writes at android <= 10 in root.

**interim solution could be like this:**

```
 public static String getStorageDir(){

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath() + "/myNewFolder";
            ....

        } else {

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myNewFolder";
        ...
    }
```

But that is suboptimal. If a user switches from Android 10 to Android 11+, then there is a big problem. What additional code do I need to allow creating a folder in ROOT on Android 11+?

It is claimed that Google Play denies "MANAGE_ALL_FILES" permission directly. Is that true and is it still the case? Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Why dont you create your folder in a public directory like Documents?

Comment: "What additional code do I need to allow creating a folder in ROOT on Android 11+?" -- that is not an option for most apps. Your only viable option for that is `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, which, as you note, is likely to cause your app to be rejected by Google. As blackapps suggests in an answer, use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, and let the user decide where on the user's device (or in the user's cloud storage) the user wants you to put the user's content.

Comment: @blackapps: As described above, this would be possible, but more for users with Android11+. It becomes problematic if a user previously had Android 10 and switched to 11. Of course, in such a case, the user could copy the content from the old to the new folder in Documents, but not everyone is tech-savvy. It would just be more elegant if it would continue to work without any problems and user activity.

Comment: There is no reason to copy content. All can stay in place. Just let the user select the old directory once.

Answer (score 1):

Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user create the wanted directory.

Comment: This will enable user to create a directory anywhere, you have no control on this

Comment: What does it matter?

Comment: It should not matter, but the TS asked specifically about creating a folder in a root folder.